# Is there a way to find out if a updated a service in WSO2 application server?

Tags: wso2

I have a simple question if it make sense in the context of WSO2 Application server.

I want to write a module, which tells me if i updated a service. The service is an axis2 SOAP service. I know how to write modules for axis2 services inside axis2 engine. But if i use the WSO2 interface, and either delete a service, update a service or add a service, Is there a way to find out that i performed these activities?.

In short, can i intercept the messages that i uploaded a new module or i uploaded a new service or i changed the service.

thanks you...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Axis2 Observer for this, take a look http://asanka.abeysinghe.org/2008/10/how-to-writing-axis2-observer.html